# Render ERB as HTML and ERB from a Rails View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, erb

I'm making a style guide where I output the code on the right that is displayed on the left.

I know that adding %% escapes ERB

I have written a helper that takes the contents of a block and renders the code in two places one showing the html and I want the other to show the source ERB that created the html.

The problem is I get back HTML where I wanted ERB.

**The View Code**

```
<%= display_code do %>
  <%= link_to "Button", "/style_guide, class: "btn" %>
<% end %>
```

**The Helper Code**

```
module StyleGuideHelper
  def display_code(&block)
    content = with_output_buffer(&block)
    html = ""
    html << content_tag(:div, content, class: "rendered-code")
    html << content_tag(:div, escape_erb(content), class: "source-code-preview")
    html.html_safe
  end

  def escape_erb(code)
    code = code.gsub("%=", "%%=")
  end
end
```

**Expected Result** 
Button <%= link_to "Button", "/style_guide, class: "btn" %>

**Actual Result**
Button Button

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that this helper runs the block (`link_to "Button", ...`) -- it never sees the source code inside the block, just its output. You could replace `escape_erb` with `h` to capture the resulting HTML, but that won't pop back up to the ERB that generated it.

As I see it, your options are:

1. Break out examples into partials, then make a helper that a) renders the partial and b) displays the underlying file.
2. Specify your ERB fragments as strings (heredocs?), pass the string into the helper, and have the helper a) evaluate it via `ERB.new(string).result(binding)` to render the result and b) display the string.
3. Make the helper determine what part of the view invoked it, then parse the .erb well enough to find the block. Catch is, the precise format of what you see in `callers` is subject to change without notice due to the way views are compiled.
4. Make a helper that uses crazy metaprogramming juju to evaluate the block in both an ERB context as well as your own special context that intercepts the code being evaluated and turns it back into markup.

...sorted in approximate order of complexity and odds of success.

Comment: I am actually searching a recipe for Option 1.

Answer (score 0):

This code below will allow you to retrieve the code for a given block.

```
class ERBSource
  ERB = ::ActionView::Template::Handlers::ERB

  def self.for(block)
    new(block).source
  end

  attr_reader :block, :file, :line_number
  def initialize(block)
    @block = block
    @file, @line_number = *block.source_location
  end

  def source
    lines = File.readlines(file)

    relevant_lines = lines[(line_number - 1)..-1] || []

    extract_first_expression(relevant_lines)
  end

  private

  def extract_first_expression(lines)
    code = lines.slice[0,1].join # add the first two lines so it has to iterate less

    lines.each do |line|
      code << line
      return code if correct_syntax?(compile_erb(code))
    end
    raise SyntaxError, "unexpected $end"
  end

  def correct_syntax?(code)
    stderr = $stderr
    $stderr.reopen(IO::NULL)
    RubyVM::InstructionSequence.compile(code)
    $stderr.reopen(stderr)
    true
  rescue Exception
    $stderr.reopen(stderr)
    false
  end

  def compile_erb(code)
    ERB.erb_implementation.new(
      code,
      :escape => false,
      :trim => (ERB.erb_trim_mode == "-")
    ).src
  end
end
```

This is what the helper looks like

```
module StyleGuideHelper
  def render_example(name, &block)
    code = ERBSource.for(block)
    content_tag(:h2, name) +
      content_tag(:div, &block) +
      content_tag(:pre, content_tag(:code, code))
  end
end
```